# Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address = 0x0) in C

Tags: c, error-handling, runtime-error

I face with

> Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address = 0x0)

whenever I try to scan a string from input to a char * variable.
I've got no idea why it occurs , because everything seems right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

headers

```
struct date {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};
```

date sructure

```
struct patientData {
    unsigned int code;
    char name[11];
    char family[21];
    unsigned int age;
    char MF;
    char disease[11];
    unsigned int numOfVisits;
    struct date *date1;
    struct date *date2;
    struct date *date3;
    struct patientData *nextPtr;

};
```

Patient data structure

```
int isEmpty (struct patientData *sPtr);
void visit ( struct patientData **returned , unsigned int code);
void Insert (struct patientData **sPtr, unsigned int code , char *name , char *family , unsigned int age ,char gender, int tmgh);
void insertDisease (struct patientData **sPtr   , char *name , char *family , char *disease );
struct patientData *searchCode (struct patientData **sPtr  , unsigned int code, int *returnval);
struct patientData *searchName (struct patientData **sPtr , char *name  , char *family);
void searchDate (struct patientData **sPtr , int year , int month , int day );
void delete (struct patientData **sPtr  );
void report (struct patientData **sPtr  );
```

functions;
here (main) is where the problem occurs.

```
int main() {

    char *choice;

    unsigned int code;
    char name[11];
    char family[21];;
    char disease[11];
    int searchCodeReturnValue;
    unsigned int age;
    char gender;
    int tmgh;
    int year , month , day;

    struct patientData *startPtr = NULL;


    puts("Enter one of the following options:");
    puts("Visit");
    puts("InsertDisease");
    puts("search");
    puts("Delete");
    puts("END");

    scanf("%s",choice);
    while (strcmp(choice, "END") != 0) {
        if (strcmp(choice, "Visit") == 0) {
            printf("Enter the code:\n");
            scanf("%5ui",&code);
            struct patientData *a = searchCode(&startPtr,code,&searchCodeReturnValue);
            if (searchCodeReturnValue == 1){
                visit(&a , code);
            }
            else if (searchCodeReturnValue == 0){
                printf("Enter name:\n");
                scanf("%10s",name);
                printf("Enter family:\n");
                scanf("%20s",family);
                printf("Enter age:\n");
                scanf("%ui",&age);
                printf("Enter gender:\n");
                scanf("%c",&gender);
                printf("Enter num of last visits:\n");
                scanf("%i",&tmgh);
                Insert(&startPtr , code , name , family , age , gender , tmgh);

            }
        }
        else if ( strcmp(choice, "InsertDisease")== 0) {
            printf("Enter name:\n");
            scanf("%10s",name);
            printf("Enter family:\n");
            scanf("%20s",family);
            printf("Enter disease:\n");
            scanf("%10s",disease);
            struct patientData *namesearch = searchName(&startPtr, name, family);
            insertDisease ( &namesearch , name , family , disease );
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "Search")== 0) {
            puts("Choose the way you wanna search: \n 1- by code \n 2- by first and last name \n 3- by Date");
            int choiceNum;
            scanf("%i",&choiceNum);
            if (choiceNum == 1) {
                printf("Enter the code:\n");
                scanf("%5ui",&code);
                searchCode(&startPtr, code , &searchCodeReturnValue);
            }
            else if ( choiceNum == 2){
                printf("Enter name:\n");
                scanf("%10s",name);
                printf("Enter family:\n");
                scanf("%20s",family);
                searchName(&startPtr ,name , family );
            }
            else if ( choiceNum == 3){
                printf("Enter year:\n");
                scanf("%i",&year);
                printf("Enter month:\n");
                scanf("%i",&month);
                printf("Enter day:\n");
                scanf("%i",&day);
                searchDate(&startPtr , year , month , day);
            }
            else
                puts("Wrong entry");
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "delete")== 0) {
            delete(&startPtr);
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "Report") == 0) {
            report(&startPtr);
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "END") == 0)
            return 0;

        else{
            puts("wrong!");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dereferencing an invalid pointer, `choice` is declared as a `char` pointer and never initialized, you don't need it to be a `char` pointer, can declare `choice` as a `char` array too, the longest string it would contain seems to be `"InsertDisease"` which has 13 characters, so declare `choice` this way

```
char choice[14];
```

and change `scanf` to

```
scanf("%13s", choice);
```

that way you prevent a buffer overflow, and a memory leak too (*which would be caused by using `malloc` if you don't properly `free` `choice` later*).

I see that you also don't rescan for `choice` value, which will make your loop infinite, you should add this to the top of the loop, and remove it outside the loop, then write the loop as

```
while (1) {
    scanf("%13s", choice);
    .
    .
   /* check the content of choice with strcmp and process the requested command */
    .
    .
}
```

in the loop you have a `if (strcmp(choice, "END") == 0) return 0;` so that should take care of ending the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *choice;
```

Memory is not allocated to the pointer and you are doing

```
scanf("%s",choice);
```

Allocate memory to the pointer and later try to scan value to it.

```
choice = malloc(30); /* Size can be anything of your wish */
```

So you are accessing uninitialized pointer which will lead to undefined behavior.

Once done with using this memory you need to free it

```
free(choice);
```

Comment: really ? but i used this style before and I never got such an error , why does it need memory allocation? '#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *mine;
    scanf("%s",mine);
    printf("%s\n",mine);
    return 0;
}'

Comment: @user21087 Yes in order to store your value to some memory location you need to have memory allocated for it. You can do the same by using `malloc()` as shown